# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::json() in Laravel5

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.1

I am trying to response a json with the json array  in Laravel5

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Event;

class EventsapiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $events =  Event::All();

        return Response::json([

                'data'=>$events

        ],200);

    }
}
```

Its giving me this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::json() in Laravel5
```

So how do we pass json in Laravel 5 ? , I Already know laravel returns automatically json array but I don't want to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the [helper function](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses):

```
return response()->json(['data'=>$events]);
```

See the docs in [\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php#L83):

```
/**
 * Return a new JSON response from the application.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $data
 * @param  int  $status
 * @param  array  $headers
 * @param  int  $options
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */

public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0)
{
    if ($data instanceof Arrayable && ! $data instanceof JsonSerializable) {
        $data = $data->toArray();
    }
    return new JsonResponse($data, $status, $headers, $options);
}
```

Comment: Oh got it the syntax has changed from 4.1 :)

Answer (score 19):

You are using:

> Illuminate\Http\Response

and should use this instead:

> \Response

Type:

```
use Response;
```

Don't type:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return data, you simply return an array from your controller method, it will render as JSON. You can return

```
return [
        'status' => true
        'data' => events
    ];
```

**Or Use Helper Function:**

```
return response()->json([''status' => true, data'=>$events]);
```

Comment: As OP stated in his question, he "Already know laravel returns automatically json array but I don't want to do that".